# Cannot access external hard disk after using it in windows 10?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, disk-management

I've tried several external hard disks without any issues, but one particular external hard drive, after using it in windows 10, when I put it back into my ubuntu system, it won't let me access its contents.

When I opened in windows 10 I just added a new folder (that's not even the one mentioned in the error).

This is the message:

[image]

My Ubuntu is 14.04, and the hard disk was already working with it, and it still does work in windows.

What can I do? It still get recognized. This is what shows me when trying to get to the disk properties:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Boot Windows, disable fast startup https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html . Shutdown (reboot often reverts the changes back to default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the file "Backup Junio 2016" cannot be displayed/edited in both Windows and Ubuntu, and gives an error in both cases.

I assume that the disk is formatted/partitioned in GPT partition table format.

## In Windows

I assume that the **disk has a NTFS partition** on it, and that it's **NOT a bootable Windows external disk**. If that's the case, attach the disk while in Windows. Then open an administrative command prompt window, and type `chkdsk /f d:` changing the "d" to the correct drive letter. This will correct any errors in the file system.

If it **IS a bootable Windows external disk**, then do this in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- reboot Windows

## In Ubuntu

Attach the disk while in Ubuntu. Open the `Disks` application from the Unity dashboard. Select the erroring disk in the left pane. Go to the "hamburger" icon in the top-right corner of the Disks window, and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Observe the data, and run the tests, and see if SMART can tell you about the condition of the drive.

Then, assuming that the drive comes up as /dev/sdb (or /dev/sd_whatever), open a `terminal` window and type `grep sdb /var/log/syslog*` (or grep sd_whatever /var/log/syslog*) and look for disk errors. If you need help interpreting what you see, upload the output text to http://paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL and I'll take a look for you.